# How to clear added entries of ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I am trying to purge the content of ListView. The problem is that when I am using `lvSerialCode.Clear();` then everything is cleared, including header information.

How can I leave header information in place, and just clear the added entries?

Should I just recreate each ListView?

```
    lvPC.Columns.Add("", 25, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
    lvPC.Columns.Add("User Name", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    lvPC.Columns.Add("Password", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
```

Comment: how about using lvSerialCode.Items.Clear();

Comment: @pratapchandra: Perfect! Thank you! This should have been an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this one to clear the items.

```
lvSerialCode.Items.Clear();
```